# Creating a simple button in libGDX

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, libgdx

I'm new to libgdx, and I've been struggling to make a simple button for hours! First I tried generating it this way(That I found on this website):

```
public class TextButtonGenerator {

    public TextButton createButton(String label){
        BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
        TextureAtlas buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("sprite.txt"));
        Skin skin = new Skin(buttonAtlas);
//        skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
        TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.font = font;
        textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("button");
        textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("button");
        textButtonStyle.checked = skin.getDrawable("button");
        return new TextButton(label, textButtonStyle);
```

I used Textpacker to create sprites.txt in my asset folder, however, the program still doesn't run, and crashes. This is the error message I'm getting:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 244475
    Process: com.mygdx.game, PID: 21525
    com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: sprite.txt (Internal)E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 244475
    Process: com.mygdx.game, PID: 21525
    com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: sprite.txt (Internal)
```

It says the root of the problem in my code is where I construct TextureAtlas. I think the problem might be that it should be .pack file not .txt? But in this tutorial they're using txt and it works fine:

https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/tutorials/libgdx-physics

I also found a different way of generating the button that did not require the pack:

```
        Skin skin = new Skin();
        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        pixmap.fill();
        skin.add("white", new Texture(pixmap));
        skin.add("default", new BitmapFont());

        TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.up = skin.newDrawable("white", new Color(0, 0, 0, 1));
        textButtonStyle.font = skin.getFont("default");
        skin.add("default", textButtonStyle);
        return new TextButton(label, skin);
```

Although this one didn't crash but there's no button! When I run it, I only get my background color on the screen. Quite frankly I don't even understand half the code I posted above, I'm trying to learn the engine on my but it just feels like I've barely made any progress in 2 days. Any help will be appreciated. Also I am adding the button to my stage and calling stage.draw() in my render method in the appropriate screen.

Comment: I don't think that extension of atlas file is important (you can change it the way you like), but it's important that beside atlas file you also have corresponding image file named the same (with different extension of course).

Comment: @MilanG I do have an image file called "sprites.png". I tried to draw some of the images as sprites, and it works but for some reason I can't draw the button. I edited the post with the error message it's giving me.

Comment: @MilanG Never mind, my txt file name was "sprites" not "sprite", aghhh hours wasted...